# Programatically navigate to a different route and pass query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am currently looking at an example from react-router's [github page](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/query-params):

### JS

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { browserHistory, Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'

const User = ({ params: { userID }, location: { query } }) => {
  let age = query && query.showAge ? '33' : ''

  return (
    <div className="User">
      <h1>User id: {userID}</h1>
      {age}
    </div>
  )
}

const App = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><Link to="/user/bob" activeClassName="active">Bob</Link></li>
      <li><Link to={{ pathname: '/user/bob', query: { showAge: true } }} activeClassName="active">Bob With Query Params</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/user/sally" activeClassName="active">Sally</Link></li>
    </ul>
    {children}
  </div>
)

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="user/:userID" component={User} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('example'))
```

### HTML

```
<!doctype html public "restroom">
<title>Query Params Example</title>
<base href="/query-params"/>
<link href="/global.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<h1 class="breadcrumbs"><a href="/">React Router Examples</a> / Query Params</h1>
<div id="example"/>
<script src="/__build__/shared.js"></script>
<script src="/__build__/query-params.js"></script>
```

That suits one of my requirements (passing a query that is not visible in url), however it only shows implementation through jsx markup. I need to programatically redirect to a route from my component, lets say redirect to `/example-route` page and have a query of `showMenu: true`, is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.props.router.push` to achieve that.

Something like this

```
this.props.router.push({
  pathname: '/example-route',
  query: { showMenu: true }
})
```

assuming that you have injected your router as props using withRouter.

[React Router Documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc)